# Evaluate an expression at singular points

Tags: evaluation

I have

```
y[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2] (5 - x - Sqrt[8 - (x + 1)^2])
{x0, x1} = {-1 - Sqrt[8], -1 + Sqrt[8]};
```

and I want to calculate

```
{y'[x0], y'[1], y'[x1]}
```

but Mathematica cannot evaluate the left and right values, nor can `Limit`.

What is the proper syntax/method to get the answer `{-Infty, 0, Infty}`?

Comment: `Limit[y'[z], z -> #] & /@ {x0, 1, x1}` gives `{-\[Infinity],0,(-I) \[Infinity]}`

Comment: I get `{Indeterminate, 0, Indeterminate}` for the above command. I use version 11.2.0.0.

Comment: mf67, it works in v9. In v12 I also get `{Indeterminate, 0, Indeterminate}`

Comment: So I might have to wait for next major update to get a v9-result? Using `{y'[x0 + 10.^-5], y'[1], y'[x0 - 10.^-5]}` to try to "go around" the problem I get `{-266.621, 0, -0.707107 + 265.915 I}`. Is there some way to have only real values returned?

Comment: mf67, i posted an answer that works in v12.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Limit` with the option [`Direction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Direction.html):

```
MapThread[ Limit[y'[z], z -> #, Direction -> #2] &, 
 {{x0, 1, x1}, {"FromAbove", "TwoSided", "FromBelow"}}]
```

> {-∞, 0, ∞}

Much simpler form (from mf67's comment below):

```
Limit[y'[z], z -> {x0, 1, x1}, Direction -> {"FromAbove", "TwoSided", "FromBelow"}]
```

> same result

```
$VersionNumber
```

> 12.

Comment: The older syntax (for people using older versions) goes like `MapThread[Limit[y'[z], z -> #, Direction -> #2] &, {{x0, 1, x1}, {-1, 0, 1}}]`

Comment: I'm trying to understand the command. I got the same result with `Limit[y'[z], z -> {x0, 1, x1}, Direction -> {"FromAbove", "TwoSided", "FromBelow"}]`. What are the differences compared to the original `MapThread`command?

Comment: @mf67, the difference is my ignorance of the fact that `Limit` is `Listable`:)